# How to list console and kernel fonts?

Tags: console, fonts, linux-kernel

I have a number of console fonts installed in `/lib/kbd/consolefonts/` installed.

1. How do I list them (obviously all I can do, is just look at the filenames, but not at a list at available fonts).
2. How can I change the console fonts?
3. How do I make a user manipulable directory for those fonts, should I use `/usr/local/lib/consolefonts/`?

Now, my kernel accepts the SYSFONT parameter: `SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16`. I'd like to have a list which fonts my kernel supports and how I can select them (as in, how do I list the kernel compiled fonts, or something).

Comment: You can list the available fonts with `fc-list`, at least. What Linux are you running?

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I want to list the fonts that are used in the text console, I don't talk about fonts used in graphical environments. Not to mention boot process.

Comment: If you must know, it's Fedora 16

Comment: I don't know of an utility to list these other than doing it manually, but to try out a font in a tty, you should use `setfont`.

Comment: `setfont` was a good idea. I got everything I need to know by now, through trial and error...

Comment: kernel fonts ? You mean framebuffer fonts ?

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: Some point of this is not completly stated at LSB. This answer was build on a Debian Squeeze (Debian 6.0.6). Some filepath and filenames may change on other distrib. Editing this answer to help me locate configs file will be welcome!

To answer as your points:

**1.** How do I list them

```
(cd /usr/share/consolefonts && find . -type f -name '*.psf.gz'; ) |
    sed 's/.\/\(.*\).psf.gz/\1/' |
    sort |
    column
```

For InKernel compiled fonts, things are differents. On Debian, running kernel have a copy of his configuration file in `/boot`:

```
grep '^CONFIG_FONT' /boot/config-2.6.32-5-amd64 
CONFIG_FONT_8x8=y
CONFIG_FONT_8x16=y
```

**2.** How can I change the console fonts?

Depending on if you want changes to be permanent:

- For immediates changes (non permanents):

`setfont -f Lat15-VGA28x16`

- For permanents changes, have a look at

`zless /usr/share/doc/console-setup/README.Debian`

`vi /etc/default/console-setup`

**3.** should I use /usr/local/lib/consolefonts/?

In fact, **yes**. You could simply (as root) create a group `consolefont`, add member to this group and change group's owner of the directory:

```
addgroup --system consolefont
chown root:consolefont /usr/local/lib/consolefonts
chmod 775 /usr/local/lib/consolefonts
adduser toto consolefont
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on debian based linux like Ubuntu you can use `consolechars` from consoletools package. Something like

```
$ consolechars -f Arabic-Fixed15.psf.gz
```

Also there is NAFE http://sourceforge.net/projects/nafe/ for editing console fonts.

`setfont` didn't work for me back then (I am talking 2008).

Comment: The package is named `console-tools` (note the `-`)